# Behaviour of :last-of-type selector on data attribute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, custom-data-attribute

May someone explain why the :first-of-type and :last-of-type selectors behave like they do in the following snippet?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaxQNJ

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 data-type data-type-a>A (should be black / is black)</h2>
  <h2 data-type data-type-a>A (should be red / is black)</h2>
  <h2 data-type data-type-b>B (should be green / is black)</h2>
  <h2 data-type data-type-b>B (should be blue / is blue)</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.container h2[data-type]:last-of-type{
  color:blue;
}

.container h2[data-type-a]:last-of-type{
  color:red;
}

.container h2[data-type-b]:first-of-type{
  color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last-of-type` and `:first-of-type` are working as expected:

> The :last-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the **last element of its type** among a group of sibling elements.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

The problem is that this particular selector is targeting the **last element** of type **`h2`**, ignoring your attribute selector. Because the **type** is `h2` and not `data-type` or `data-type-a`.

I'd recommend you to use `class`, it's what it's meant to:

```css
div {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.data-type-b {
  color: green;
}

.data-type-a {
  color: red;
}

.data-type:first-child {
  color: inherit;
}

.data-type:last-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="data-type data-type-a">A (should be black / is black)</h2>
  <h2 class="data-type data-type-a">A (should be red / is red)</h2>
  <h2 class="data-type data-type-b">B (should be green / is green)</h2>
  <h2 class="data-type data-type-b">B (should be blue / is blue)</h2>
</div>
```